# erro no sublime

Tags: sublime-text

Ontem usei o sublime normalmente, mas hoje quando o execultei apresentou o seguinte erro

[image: erro sublime]

Podem me ajudar ?

Comment: tente remover o tema monokai do seu sublime ou verificar se há atualização.

Comment: como verifico novas atualizações ou removo o tema ?

Comment: vc consegue abrir o sublime e acessar o package control mesmo com esse erro?

Comment: consigo acessar o package control

Comment: Clique no menu no topo "Preferences", depois acesse "Settings". Do lado direito irá visualizar suas configurações pessoais, procure a linha "color_scheme" e remova, salve e veja se resolve.

Comment: eu consegui achar a linha, mas o arquivos não consigo editar, apagar, não consigo fazer nem uma mudança.

Answer (score 0):

remove o tema normalmente:

> ctrl + shift +  p > "Package Control: Remove Package"

procura por "ColorHighlighter". Depois instala ele de novo

Comment: Desinstalei o Color Highlighter mas mesmo assim continua o erro